# Encountered error while trying to install package. lxml

Tags: lxml, docxtpl

work/Versions/3.9/Headers -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
src/lxml/etree.c:96:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include "Python.h"
^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
cc -arch x86_64 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/cf/lh0781v528b2s9g1hk8v7bg40000gn/T/xmlXPathInit1vfqpnc0.c -o var/folders/cf/lh0781v528b2s9g1hk8v7bg40000gn/T/xmlXPathInit1vfqpnc0.o
cc -arch x86_64 var/folders/cf/lh0781v528b2s9g1hk8v7bg40000gn/T/xmlXPathInit1vfqpnc0.o -lxml2 -o a.out
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

Try using pip3 install lxml, But the above problems still occur

Answer (score 0):

Try installing outside venv. That's the only option that worked for me.